How to set Dark theme in Blazor project
How to set dark theme as default in Blazor project. Not toggle thing just when u enter the application there's already dark theme.
I went through some of the files like app.css from wwwroot and bootstrap.min.css from bootstrap folder and get something like this: "background-color: #1b6ec2;". I dont realy understand what does it mean. I tried to alter some values but nothing changed(.

Why not do it the Blazor way? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-9.0

Bootstrap 5.3 added dark mode, so first update your bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.css.map to 5.3+ (just get the latest)
Make your site dark mode by adding data-bs-theme="dark" to the html tag.
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="dark">

Then you will need to go through the app.css and any scoped CSS files (in the default project that would be app.css, MainLayout.razor.css and NavMenu.razor.css) - remove any hardcoded colors.
That should get you started.
Read more


in wich file is html tag?

my version is 5.3.3, i suppose this is the latest.

@saidrajabov - "in wich file" depends on your application type, which you didn't specify. But Ctrl+Shift+F will find it for you.

@HenkHolterman it's Blazor Web App

@HenkHolterman i found its location, it's in app.razor. i added (data-bs-theme="dark") but it doesnt work((

Make sure you clear cache and refresh in your browser (open the browser dev tools, then press Shift+Ctrl+P, then type Clear Site Data and hit Enter, then press F5)

Once you have refreshed, check to make sure data-bs-theme is set on the html element
